# Return element from Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I am trying to return element from Thread. And I have wrote this piece of code to do this. But my code sometime works correctly, but sometime not. Please help me to understand, what is wrong with this code. I am learning multi-threading in C#

Correct result
[CorrectResultImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fIRR.jpg)

Not correct
[Not correect result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcDwE.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Thread_CallBack_Method
{
    public delegate int CallBackDelegate(int sumofNumbers);

    class Program
    {
        public static int Sum(int sum)
        {
            return sum;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallBackDelegate callback = new CallBackDelegate(Sum);
            Numbers numbers = new Numbers(3, callback);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(numbers.sumOfNumbers);
            t1.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of elements = {0} ",numbers.returnElementFromThread());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Numbers
    {
        int _number;
        CallBackDelegate _callBack;

        public Numbers(int number, CallBackDelegate callback)
        {
            this._number = number;
            this._callBack = callback;
        }

        int threadElement;
        public void sumOfNumbers()
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= _number; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }

            if (_callBack != null)
                threadElement = _callBack(sum);
        }

        public int returnElementFromThread()
        {
            return threadElement;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, you're better off if you don't say "return" when you're talking about threads.  A thread is not a method:  You don't "call" a thread, you _start_ it; and a thread doesn't "return," it _ends_ or it _terminates_.  The difference is, if method A calls method B, then A can not do anything until B returns; but if method A starts a new thread, then you have two threads that are running _concurrently_.  Communication between threads is always through _shared variables_.  If thread A computes a value that thread B will need, then thread B must know both _where_ to look for it, and _when_ to look.

Comment: Thanks! It was a good explanation of differences between method and thread

Answer (score 3):

Because the thread is either completing before or after you print the result to the console.  If you're going to have to wait for the result anyway, why are you bothering to use another thread?

Using threading is only useful when you want to perform operations simultaneously, or leave the UI responsive so the user doesn't get frustrated.  What you have is a simple serial execution of code...using threading here isn't necessary.